# quicksort special case - seems to be a faulty algorithm from K&R

Tags: c, quicksort

I have a problem understanding quicksort algorithm (the simplified version without  pointers) from K&R. There is already a thorough explanation provided by Dave Gamble here [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231254/kr-qsort-example-with-pointers-and-arrays-confusion). 
However I noticed that by starting with a slightly changed string we can obtain no swaps during many loops of the for loop.
Firstly the code:

```
void qsort(int v[], int left, int right)
{
    int i, last;

    void swap(int v[], int i, int j);

    if (left >= right) /* do nothing if array contains */
            return;         /* fewer than two elements */
    swap(v, left, (left + right)/2); /* move partition elem */
    last = left;                    /* to v[0] */
    for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++) /* partition */
            if (v[i] < v[left])
                    swap(v, ++last, i);
    swap(v, left, last);                  /* restore partition elem */
    qsort(v, left, last-1);
    qsort(v, last+1, right);
}
```

Walkthrough in my opinion:

we start with CADBE; left=0; right=4; D is the pivot
so according to algorithm we swap D with C obtaining DACBE

last = left =0

i = 1  if ( v[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231254/kr-qsort-example-with-pointers-and-arrays-confusion) < v[0] ) it is true so we swap v[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231254/kr-qsort-example-with-pointers-and-arrays-confusion) (because last is incremented before operation) with v[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231254/kr-qsort-example-with-pointers-and-arrays-confusion) so nothing changes, last = 1, still having DACBE;

now i = 2 if ( v[2] < v[0] ) -> true so we swap v[2] with v[2] nothing changed again; last = 2

now i = 3 if ( v[3] < v[0] ) -> true so we swap v[3] with v[3] nothing changed AGAIN (!), last = 3

So apparently something is wrong, algorithm does nothing. 
Your opinions appreciated very much. I must be wrong, authors are better than me ;D
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have not finished the walk through. What happens after the last swap, just before the first recursive call to qsort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop goes from `left + 1` up to *and including* `right`.  When `i=4`, the test fails and `last` does not get incremented.

Then the recursive calls sort `BACDE` with `left=0,right=2` and `left=4,right=4`.  (Which is correct when `D` is the pivot.)

Comment: Thanks. But when it comes to recursive calls don't we start with BACDE with left=0 and right=2 (last-1) ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it just so happened that your input sub-array `ACBE` is already partitioned by `D` (`ACB` is smaller than `D` and `E` is bigger than `D`), so it is not surprising the partitioning cycle does not physically swap any values.

In reality, it is not correct to say that it "does nothing". It does not reorder anything in the cycle, since your input data need no extra reordering. But it still does one thing: it finds the value of `last` that says where smaller elements end and bigger elements begin, i.e. it separates `ACBE` into `ACB` and `E` parts. The cycle ends with `last == 3`, which is the partitioning point for further recursive steps.