# Reuse comparison function

Tags: c, void-pointers, avl-tree, qsort

I have builded a binary tree using an AVL and then data is packed in an array

```
typedef struct {
    void **data;
    int count;
} t_table;
```

The comparison function looks like:

```
int cmp(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    int a = *(int *)pa;
    int b = *(int *)pb;

    if (a > b)
        return +1;
    else
    if (b > a)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

I am inserting in avl-tree and sorting the array of pointers using [K&R qsort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231254/kr-qsort-example-with-pointers-and-arrays-confusion) without problems.

Now I want to use the sandard function `qsort` of `<stdlib.h>` but I am forced to use a new function for `t_table` (due to pointer conversion required by `qsort`), it looks like:

```
int cmp(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    int a = *(int*)(*(void**)pa);
    int b = *(int*)(*(void**)pb);

    if (a > b)
        return +1;
    else
    if (b > a)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

I understand why the function must be changed (quoting C-FAQ):

> To understand why the curious pointer conversions in a qsort
>   comparison function are necessary (and why a cast of the function
>   pointer when calling qsort can't help), it's useful to think about how
>   qsort works. qsort doesn't know anything about the type or
>   representation of the data being sorted: it just shuffles around
>   little chunks of memory. (All it knows about the chunks is their size,
>   which you specify in qsort's third argument.) To determine whether two
>   chunks need swapping, qsort calls your comparison function. (To swap
>   them, it uses the equivalent of memcpy.)

But I wonder if there is any alternative (using `stdlib qsort`) to avoid having to maintain two comparison functions (one for avl and another for `void **`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can really avoid to maintain these 2 functions, but you can do something like this:

```
int cmp_int(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    int a = *(int *)pa;
    int b = *(int *)pb;

    return cmp(a, b);
}

int cmp_voidp(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
   int a = *(int*)(*(void**)pa);
   int b = *(int*)(*(void**)pb);

   return cmp(a, b);
}

static int cmp(const int a, const int b)
{
    if (a > b)
        return +1;
    else
    if (b > a)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

You have 3 functions, but you don't repeat yourself and it's more easy to maintain.

**EDIT:** Like *Sergey L.* said, if you're using `C99`, `cmp` could be a `static inline` function.

Comment: define `cmp` as `static inline` for additional performance (`gnu99++` standard)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use exactly the same function, but you can define the second in terms of the first:

```
int cmp2(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    return cmp(*(void **)pa, *(void **)pb);
}
```